# Spring Data MongoDB GroupOperation convert to ObjectID

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, aggregation

I've been googling for a while and can't find a solution. Perhaps I'm creating my lookup wrong, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have two collections where one references the ID of another collection and is stored as a string. NOTE: before you ask, I can't convert the "parentId" to an ObjectId in the collection.

Car collection:

```
{
  id: ObjectId("1234")
  ... other car fields ...
},
{
  id: ObjectId("2345")
  ... other car fields ...
}
```

Comments collection

```
{
  id: ObjectId("3456"),
  commentMessage: "this is a comment",
  parentRecordId: "1234"
},
{
  id: ObjectId("4567"),
  commentMessage: "this is another comment",
  parentRecordId: "2345"
}
```

I am using Spring Data MongoDB with MongoDB version 3.6.  Here's my query, and I can't for the life of me get it to return the matching Car objects.

```
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny("comment");
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("parentRecordId");
LookupOperation lookup = Aggregation.lookup("car", "_id", "_id", "car");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group, lookup);

AggregationResults<CommentAggregationResults> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, CommentAggregationResults.class);
```

Here's the model object CommentAggregationResults.class

```
public class CommentAggregationResults(){
  @Id
  private String id;
  private Car car;

  ... getters and setters ...
}
```

What I expect from this query is two responses from the database. Inside my CommentAggregationResults class I should see the Car ID in the "id" field and the Car object itself in the "car" field. (I'm going to build on this query to make it more useful, I just need to get past this step first).

What I'm seeing in my results, is two CommentAggregationResults objects (as expected) - The id is set correctly. However the Car object is null.

My theory is that I need to somehow convert the "parentRecordId" string into an ObjectId within this query.

How do I do that? Or is there another way to achieve my desired results?

Comment: LookupOperation lookup = Aggregation.lookup("comment", "_id", "_id", "car");
you are making lookup on your comments schema. might it needs to hit on car schema

Comment: That was a typo, my apologies, my problem is still relevant though